# Unstable WiFi connection on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04

After I switched to Ubuntu, the WiFi started to disconnect randomly.
It was solved for some time for an unknown reason, but it started again.
I tried all the solution except the solution to set the router bandwidth because I don't have access to the router. Also, my Ethernet cable is broken, so using it is not an option as it will be also be unstable.

`sudo dmesg | grep -i wlp2s`: https://hasteb.in/epedegut.yaml
`iwconfig`: https://hasteb.in/nuxodizu.yaml
`sudo lspci`: https://hasteb.in/ridagezo.yaml
`sudo lsusb`: https://hasteb.in/joqudeqe.css

Comment: Ok, I have 3 possible solutions in my head already, but first could you provide the output of the following commands: `sudo ifconfig` , `sudo iwconfig`, `sudo lspci` , `sudo lsusb` ,  `sudo dmesg | grep -i wlan0` , and  `sudo uname -a` so we know what system and NIC we are working with.

Comment: https://hasteb.in/nasumoca.yaml

Comment: Great, actually the best way to add such outputs is to encapsulate them into the original post itself. If you provide the links, I'll take care of the formatting. Please change the `dmesg` line to  `sudo dmesg | grep -i wlp2s`

Comment: Okay, I edited the original answer to include the output of the command.

Comment: You still need to provide the output of `iwconfig` and `sudo lspci` and `sudo lsusb`.

Comment: Added all of those.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the logs.

Your WIFI controller is `AC 3168NGW` , but this fix will not be limited to that particular NIC, but may also work for WIFI controllers using the `iwlwifi` as the kernel driver.

---

#### 1. Checking your WIFI kernel driver, as well as log lines describing the issue

Start by running ([02:00.0] corresponds to the pci device address of WIFI per your logs):

```
sudo lspci -k -s 02:00.0
```

And the output should show the kernel driver like so:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

The recent kernel upgrade changed a few things, among them was the Beacon Interval. You can confirm the beacon issue by running

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

And you should see lines resembling:

```
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
```

---

#### 2. How to fix it

In order to fix it (**this is a widespread bug, that affected multiple kernel drivers across various distros, appears to be related to lines of code in `mac80211.c`) please do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

and in the `nano` editor add the foilowing two lines:

```
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
options iwlwifi power_save=0
```

Save the file (in `nano` you can do so with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)

and reboot with `sudo init 6`

When the system reboots you can confirm that the module options are in effect by running

```
sudo systool -vm iwlmvm | grep power
sudo systool -vm iwlwifi | grep power
```

and checking their output for the corresponding values you just set

---

**EDIT:** My original suggestion to use `modinfo` to check whether our options get set was not correct. The error was spotted by @Zoltan, and his suggestion to use `systool` instead will result in the values of parameters initialized through modprobe `options` being displayed in the terminal output.

Comment: I tried this, but power scheme looks like it hasn't changed: `power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)`

Comment: ok can you try the following command ` sudo modprobe -r iwlmvm && sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlmvm power_scheme=1 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi power_save=0`. DONT reboot, but again check the `sudo modinfo iwlmvm | grep power` and `sudo modinfo iwlwifi | grep power` if they show the correct new parameters, then we will just have to narrow down what causes them to reset back on reboot.

Comment: Oop, that killed my wifi, and had to restart to get the wifi device back.

Comment: you typically never have to resort to a restart to get your wifi device back online. Have you tried to  restart the `networking` and/or `network-manager` services. . Also can you be more specific with regards to "that killed my wifi". What happened? No connection? No device? No name resolution No address/routes? no Authentication?

Comment: My wifi icon disappeared completely, and I had to restart to get internet back working. I didn't experiment it with it much.

Comment: Also, powersave won't do anything for me. It asks for a password when it breaks for long enough, while I ALREADY entered the password.

Comment: `modinfo` does not show the current value of a setting, just the possible values and the default one. Use `systool -vm iwlmvm` to get the current value.

Comment: @Zoltan, Good catch! You are absolutely right, `modinfo` only displays the available parameter options, but not their actual values themselves, as `modinfo` only parses the information allocated with `MODULE_PARM_DESC()` macro used inside the module source files. It has no knowledge of any values, as the corresponding variables only need to be initialized before the `module_parm()` and `module_parm_desc()` macros, and `modinfo` cannot tell what happens at load in or later as it only looks at the module source code. I typically look at `/sys/module/*/parameters` but `systool` works even better.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling wifi powersave by adding

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

into the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-off.conf`.
Then restart the NetworkManager by running `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55) is a reference for that.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.10
I solved this for myself by going to Settings > Power > Power Saving > Automatic Suspend and toggling the value to Off.

Comment: Isn't that for screen? It seems to affect nothing.

Comment: I thought so, too, but after I set the value to Off, my wifi stopped disconnecting, I have a lot of guesses about the reasons and what it does, but I really don't know why it worked for me.

Comment: Let me try that setting for a week, and see if that helps.

Comment: No, the screen does shut off when this happens, but automatic suspend actually puts the system fully to sleep.  I've seen Linux systems that can suspend and resume within a second or two (fast enough where you'd think it's just blanking and unblanking the screen.)  It does in fact disconnect the wifi on suspend (since it then turns the wifi chip completely off) and reconnect when you resume; if you're in the middle of a download, and catch it's suspended within like 30 to maybe 60 seconds, you're OK, otherwise, your downloads time out.

Comment: Ah, seems like a completely different situation there. My Wi-Fi keeps disconnecting when I'm actively using it.